# Deploy Angular5 app in GitHub

Tags: angular5, deploying

When I enter

```
$ angular-cli-ghpages
```

on Angular's CLI I'm getting following error:

[image: Error which I'm getting]

How can I fix this?
Actually this is my first time deploying in git and I'm following a tutorial.